# FullCalendar strange behavior deleting event from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-5

I need your help to understand the behaviour of my instance of FullCalendar Scheduler v5.5.0.

My event source is a JSON array generated by a basic SQL request from database, each event with it's own unique id as usual.

I'm using some jQuery code to make ajax calls to insert / update / delete events.

Everything works well but when i want to delete multiple events one after another without reloading page, then the ajax call to delete script is done multiple times for each event.

e.g : I want to delete the event with the id 2674, I click the button made for and it triggers the ajax call to the delete script (at this step i can see one call to the delete.php page in the network tab of the devtool console with the id 2674 in the post request) and everything is ok, event is deleted on the view.

But when I delete another event just after (id: 2631), then I have 3 calls to the delete script, the first and second with the id 2674 in the post request (the event I have deleted first) and the last one with the id 2631 as expected.

If I repeat this action again i have 6 calls to the delete.php page:

- the first and second with the id 2674 in the post request (the event i have deleted first),
- the third with the id 2631 (the event i have deleted in second),
- the 4th with the id 2674 (the event i have deleted first),
- the 5th with the id 2631 (the event i have deleted in second),
  and the last one with the id 2651 as expected.

Here is my code, **do you have an idea to explain this behavior ?**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var initialLocaleCode = 'fr';
  var url ='./';
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    locale: 'fr',
    firstDay: 1,
    hiddenDays: [0], // hide Tuesdays and Thursdays
    selectable: true,
    slotDuration: '00:20:00',
    slotMinTime: '08:00:00',
    slotMaxTime: '20:00:00',
    allDaySlot: false,
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev next today',
      center: 'title',
      //right: 'resourceTimeGridDay,dayGridMonth,timeGridDay,listDay,listWeek'
      right: 'resourceTimeGridDay,resourceTimeGridSixDay,dayGridMonth'
    },
    titleFormat: { // will produce something like "Tuesday, September 18, 2018"
      month: 'long',
      year: 'numeric',
      day: 'numeric',
      weekday: 'long'
    },
    views: {
      listDay: { buttonText: 'list day' },
      listWeek: { buttonText: 'list week' },
      dayGridMonth: { buttonText: 'Mois' },
      timeGridDay: { buttonText: 'Jour' },
      resourceTimeGridDay: { buttonText: 'Jour'},
      resourceTimeGridSixDay: {
        type: 'resourceTimeGrid',
        duration: { days: 6 },
        buttonText: 'Semaine',

      }
    },
    datesAboveResources:true,
    nowIndicator: true,
    contentHeight: 900,
    initialView: 'resourceTimeGridDay',
    initialDate: curdate,
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    editable: true,
    dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    resources: [
      {
        title: 'Frédéric Xavier',
        id: 'fred'
      }, {
        title: 'Emmanuelle Chouin',
        id: 'manu'
      }
    ],
    eventDidMount: function(info) {
      var start = info.event.start;
      var end = info.event.end;
      var startTime;
      var endTime;
      if (!start) {
        startTime = '';
      } else {
        startTime = start;
        startevent = start.toLocaleTimeString([], { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' });
      }

      if (!end) {
        endDate = '';
        endevent ='';
      } else {
        endTime = end;
        endevent = end.toLocaleTimeString([], { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' });
      }
      var title = startevent + " - " + endevent + " " + info.event.title;
      var description = info.event.extendedProps.description;
      if (!info.event.extendedProps.description) {
        description = '';
      }
      $(info.el).popover({
        title: title,
        placement:'top',
        trigger : 'hover',
        content: description,
        container:'body'
      });

      $('.popover.in').remove(); //<--- Remove the popover 
      //$(info.el).popover('show');
      if(info.event.extendedProps.description){          
        $(info.el).find(".fc-event-title").append(" <i class='fas fa-exclamation-triangle fa-lg red-text'></i>");
      }
    },
    dateClick: function(info) {
      $('#event').modal('show');
      var str = info.dateStr
      $('#datedeb').val(str.substring(0,10)).focusin();
      $('#heuredeb').val(str.substring(11,  str.indexOf(':00+'))).focusin();
      $("input[name='resource'][value='" + info.resource.id + "']").prop('checked', true);
      var twentyMinutesLater = new Date(str);
      twentyMinutesLater.setTime(twentyMinutesLater.getTime() + 20*60000);
      var test = twentyMinutesLater + ' ';
      $('#heurefin').val(removeN(test, 16).substring(0,5)).focusin();
    },
    select: function(info) {
      var str = info.startStr
      var str2 = info.endStr
      $('#event').modal('show');
      $('#datedeb').val(str.substring(0,10)).focusin();
      $('#heuredeb').val(str.substring(11,  str.indexOf(':00+'))).focusin();
      $("input[name='resource'][value='" + info.resource.id + "']").prop('checked', true);
      $('#heurefin').val(str2.substring(11,  str2.indexOf(':00+'))).focusin();
    },
    events: url+'api/load.php',
    eventDrop: function(arg) {
      var madate = arg.event.startStr;
      var datedeb = madate.substring(0,10);
      var heuredeb = madate.substring(11,madate.indexOf(':00+'))
      var end = arg.event.endStr;
      var heurefin = end.substring(11,end.indexOf(':00+'))
      $.ajax({
        url:url+"/api/update.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:{id:arg.event.id, date:datedeb, start:heuredeb, end:heurefin, title:arg.event.title,color:arg.event.backgroundColor, commentaire:arg.event.extendedProps.description, resource:arg.event._def.resourceIds[0]},
      });
      
      calendar.refetchEvents();
    },
    eventDragStop: function(arg) {
      $('.popover').remove(); //<--- Remove the popover 
      calendar.refetchEvents();
      $('.popover').remove(); //<--- Remove the popover 
    },
    eventResize: function(arg) {
      var madate = arg.event.startStr;
      var datedeb = madate.substring(0,10);
      var heuredeb = madate.substring(11,madate.indexOf(':00+'))
      var end = arg.event.endStr;
      var heurefin = end.substring(11,end.indexOf(':00+'))

      $.ajax({
        url:url+"api/update.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:{id:arg.event.id, date:datedeb, start:heuredeb, end:heurefin, title:arg.event.title,color:arg.event.backgroundColor, commentaire:arg.event.extendedProps.description, resource:arg.event._def.resourceIds[0]},
      });
      calendar.refetchEvents();
      //location.reload();
    },
    eventClick: function(arg) {
      var id = arg.event.id;
      $('#editEventId').val(id);
      $('#deleteEvent').attr('data-id', id); 
      //$('#modif').modal('show');

      $.ajax({
        url:url+"api/getevent.php",
        type:"POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{id:id},
        success: function(data) {
          $('#edit-nom').val(data[0].title).focusin();
          $('#edit-commentaire').val(data[0].description).focusin();
          $('#edit-datedeb').val(data[0].start.substring(0,10)).focusin();
          //alert(data[0].start.substring(11,data[0].start.indexOf(':00')));
          $('#edit-heuredeb').val(data[0].start.substring(11,data[0].start.length+5)).focusin();
          $('#edit-heurefin').val(data[0].end.substring(11,data[0].end.length+5)).focusin();
          $("input[name='editcolor'][value='" + data[0].backgroundColor + "']").prop('checked', true);
          $("input[name='edit-resource'][value='" + data[0].resourceId + "']").prop('checked', true);
          $('.Nom').replaceWith('<span class="Nom font-weight-bold text-danger">'+data[0].title+'</span>');
                
          $('#modif').modal('show');
        }
      });

      $(document).on('click', '#deleteEvent', function() {
        $('#modif').modal('hide');
        $('#modalConfirmDelete').modal('show');
        $('#delete').replaceWith('<button type="button" class="btn  btn-outline-danger" id="delete" data-id="'+id+'">Oui</button>');

        $(document).on('click', '#delete', function() {
          $.ajax({
            url:url+"api/delete.php",
            type:"POST",
            cache : false,
            data:{id:id},
            success: function(msg) { 
              console.log(msg);
              $('#modalConfirmDelete').modal('hide');
              calendar.refetchEvents(); 
            },
          });
        });
      });
    }
  });

  calendar.render();

  $(document).on('click', '#createEvent', function(event) {
    var request_method = $("#form").attr("method");
    var post_url = $( "#form").attr('action');
    var post_data = $( "#form" ).serialize();

    $.ajax({
      type: request_method,
      url: post_url,
      data: post_data,
      success: function(msg) { 
        $("#form")[0].reset();
        $('#event').modal('hide');
        console.log(msg);
        calendar.refetchEvents();
      },
      error: function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
      }
    });
  });

  $(document).on('click', '#editEvent', function(event) {
    var request_method = $("#formupdate").attr("method");
    var post_url = $( "#formupdate").attr('action');
    var post_data = $( "#formupdate" ).serialize();

    $.ajax({
      type: request_method,
      url: post_url,
      data: post_data,
      success: function(msg) { 
        console.log(msg);
        $("#formupdate")[0].reset();
        $('#modif').modal('hide');
        calendar.refetchEvents();
      },
      error: function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Next time you ask a question here, we don't need your entire code - just the bits which are relevant to the problem will do. e..g. if the problem is with deleting events, then just the basic calendar setup and the deletion code will be needed. The creation code probably doesn't make any difference. See the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for relevant guidance. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are piling up event handlers. Every time you click on any event on the calendar, `eventClick` runs. Within event click, you run `$(document).on('click', '#deleteEvent', function() {` which adds a new "click" handler to show the deletion modal. Then every time the modal is shown, it runs `$(document).on('click', '#delete', function() {` which adds a new "click" event handler to the Delete button...but your code never removes any of the event handlers which were previously added to those buttons.

Therefore it appears to work fine the first time you delete something, but subsequently if you press Delete again, it will run **all** the "click" event handlers associated with the button. That's why you can see it running requests for events you had deleted previously - it's re-running event handlers which are still attached to the button. You can use [off()](https://api.jquery.com/off/) in jQuery to remove existing event handlers from an element.

e.g.

```
$(document).off('click', '#deleteEvent');
$(document).on('click', '#deleteEvent', function() {

//....

  $(document).off('click', '#delete');
  $(document).on('click', '#delete', function() {
```